# Unable to connect to server using its name "Connect-VIServer "

Tags: powershell, vmware-vsphere, powercli

I wrote the following PowerCLI command to connect to a server by its name :-

```
Connect-VIServer -Server "t***.v****ces.intra" -User root -Password "*****"
```

but I got the following error:-

```
Connect-VIServer : 07/08/2015 13:11:54    Connect-VIServer        Could not resolve the requested VC server.
ConnectionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Client20_ConnectivityServiceImpl_Reconnect_NameR
   esolutionFailure,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.ConnectVISer
  ver
```

now if I replace the server name with the server IP the command will work well. so can anyone advice why I am unable to connect to server by its name?

Comment: What happens if you ping the FQDN you're trying to connect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (the little) that i know:

If

- you own the domain name
- and this domain name is registered to a Registration Authority
- and the entry is being added correctly into the Zone file of a Name Server
- and the propagation time is elapsed (depending on the TLS setted in Zone file)

Then

it should work